# How to print a text file thru Printer print data by using C# window services

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to print a text file based on given filename through a printer automatically with out any manual hand work it was doing in C sharp window services, it was not working for me , any one give me suggestions .

```
using System.Management; 

    private Font printFont;
    private StreamReader streamToPrint;

 private void GetPrinters(string fileName)
    {

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM  Win32_Printer");

        string printerName = "";
        foreach (ManagementObject printer in searcher.Get()) 
        {
        printerName = printer["Name"].ToString().ToLower();
        if (printerName.Equals(@"\\chenraqdc1.raqmiyat.local\hp laserjet black chennai"))
            {
              Console.WriteLine("Printer = " + printer["Name"]); 
                 if (printer["WorkOffline"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("true"))
                    {
                         // printer is offline by user
                        label1.Text = "Your Plug-N-Play printer is not connected.";
                    }
                 else
                    {streamToPrint = new StreamReader(fileName);

                    printFont = new Font("Arial", 10);
                    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
                    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler
                       (this.pd_PrintPage);
                    pd.Print();

                    streamToPrint.Close();
                    }
            }
        }
     }
            private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
        {
        float linesPerPage = 0;
        float yPos = 0;
        int count = 0;
        float leftMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Left;
        float topMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Top;
        string line = null;

        // Calculate the number of lines per page.
        linesPerPage = ev.MarginBounds.Height /
           printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics);

        // Print each line of the file.
        while (count < linesPerPage &&
           ((line = streamToPrint.ReadLine()) != null))
        {
            yPos = topMargin + (count *
               printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics));
            ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Black,
               leftMargin, yPos, new StringFormat());
            count++;
        }
```

Comment: do i need to set any printer settings , y it is not getting printed

Comment: code is not throwing any error, pd.Print(); system comes upto this line it was showing one small dialog box printing the document but file it is not getting printed, any way kindly help how to disable that printing dialog box

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...

Note : this is sample code how to print pdf file using c# window services, if you want to print the text files you can change this code

Windows Form with a Button (cmdGetPrinters) and a ListView
   (lstPrinters). The list view has two columns defined - "Property" and
   "Value" which would describe the printers installed on the local
   machine. The following code does the magic.

```
using System;                                                              
using System.Collections.Generic;                                          
using System.ComponentModel;                                                
using System.Data; System.Drawing;                                         
using System.Text; System.Windows.Forms;                                   
using System.Management;                                                   
using System.Management.Instrumentation;                                    

public partial class frmPrintDisplay : Form                                 
{                                                                           
 public frmPrintDisplay()                                               
 {                                                                      
      InitializeComponent();                                            
 }                                                                      

 private void cmdGetPrinters_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)          
 {                                                                      
     ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");

     ManagementObjectSearcher mo = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query); 

     ManagementObjectCollection printers = mo.Get();                    

    foreach (ManagementObject printer in printers)                      
    {                                                                  
        PropertyDataCollection printerProperties = printer.Properties;  
        string printerPath = printer.Path.ToString() ;                  
        PropertyDataCollection.PropertyDataEnumerator test =            
            printer.Properties.GetEnumerator();                         

        while(! (test.MoveNext()== false ))                             
        {                                                               
            lstPrinters.Items.Add(                                      
                new ListViewItem( new string[]                          
                {                                                       
                    test.Current.Name,                                  
                    (                                                  
                        (test.Current.Value == null) ?                  
                        "n/a" : test.Current.Value.ToString()           
                    )                                                   
                })                                                      
            );                                                         
         }                                                               
      }                                                                   
    }                                                                       
  }
```

This image shows the result of this small windows app. Note the "Name" property, this will be used to send the text file to the printer. This is shown under the "ShareName" property of the printer. On a test machine, which is also in the same domain/workgroup,you have to  install a new network printer, and pointed the installation to look at the shared printer on the first computer. This in effect made the first computer a printer server, and you able to closelly replicate the setup for the client.

Now onto the test machine... The application above mentioned `code building` saves the text files into a temporary directory called C:\Program Files[Application Name]\Temp\

```
  using System;                                                              
  using System.Collections.Generic;                                          
  using System.ComponentModel;                                                
  using System.Data; System.Drawing;                                         
  using System.IO;                                                           
  using System.Text; System.Windows.Forms;                                   
  using System.Management;                                                   
  using System.Management.Instrumentation;                                    



 private void print(ref DirectoryInfo tempDir)                               
 {                                                                          
   try                                                                    
   {                                                                       
    foreach(FileInfo file in tempDir.GetFiles("*.pdf"))                 
    {                                                                   
        file.CopyTo("\\\\XYZ\\Phaser77\\" + file.Name);                 
    }                                                                   
   }                                                                      
   catch(Exception ee){ }                                                  
 }
```

i hope it will helps you